# why runtime error on online judge?

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am unable to understand why i am getting runtime error with this code. Problem is every number >=6 can be represented as sum of two prime numbers.
My code is ...... Thanks in advance problem link is http://poj.org/problem?id=2262

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define N 1000000

int main()
{

    long int i,j,k;
    long int *cp = malloc(1000000*sizeof(long int));
    long int *isprime = malloc(1000000*sizeof(long int));
    //long int *isprime;
    long int num,flag;
    //isprime = malloc(2*sizeof(long int));
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        isprime[i]=1;
    }
    j=0;
    for(i=2;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(isprime[i])
        {
            cp[j] = i;
            j++;
            for(k=i*i;k<N;k+=i)
            {
                isprime[k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    //{
    //    printf("%d ",cp[i]);
    //}
    //printf("\n");
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%ld",&num);
        if(num==0) break;
        flag = 0;
        for(i=0;i<j&&num>cp[i];i++)
        {
            //printf("%d ",cp[i]);
            if(isprime[num-cp[i]])
            {
                printf("%ld = %ld + %ld\n",num,cp[i],num-cp[i]);
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            printf("Goldbach's conjecture is wrong.\n");
        }
    }
    free(cp);
    free(isprime);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime error?  You should check `cp` and `isprime` for `NULL` in case the `malloc`s failed, it could be that your heap is not large enough.

Comment: It would help if you could tell use more, like what runtime error you get? Does it work when you run it yourself? Does it compile with any warnings? (Warning messages are often a sing of you doing something technically legal but weird and that can be undefined behavior).

Comment: Server doesn't response with any specific type of error and also it compile without any error or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two *possibilities* immediately spring to mind. The first is that the user input may be failing if whatever test harness is being used does not provide any input. Without knowing more detail on the harness, this is a guess at best.

You could check that by hard-coding a value rather than accepting one from standard input.

The other possibility is the rather large memory allocations being done. It may be that you're in a constrained environment which doesn't allow that.

A simple test for that is to drop the value of `N` (and, by the way, use it rather than the multiple hardcoded `1000000` figures in your `malloc` calls). A better way would be to check the return value from `malloc` to ensure it's not NULL. That should be done anyway.

And, aside from that, you may want to check your Eratosthenes Sieve code. The first item that should be marked non-prime for the prime `i` is `i + i` rather than `i * i` as you have. I think it should be:

```
for (k = i + i; k < N; k += i)
```

The *mathematical algorithm* is actually okay since any multiple of `N` less than `N * N` will already have been marked non-prime by virtue of the fact it's a multiple of one of the primes previously checked.

Your problem lies with integer overflow. At the point where `N` becomes `46_349`, `N * N` is `2_148_229_801` which, if you have a 32-bit two's complement integer (maximum value of `2_147_483_647`), will wrap around to `-2_146_737_495`.

When that happens, the loop keeps going since that negative number is still less than your limit, but using it as an array index is, shall we say, inadvisable :-)

The reason it works with `i + i` is because your limit is well short of `INT_MAX / 2` so no overflow happens there.

If you want to make *sure* that this won't be a problem if you get up near `INT_MAX / 2`, you can use something like:

```
for (k = i + i; (k < N) && (k > i); k += i)
```

That extra check on `k` should catch the wraparound event, provided your wrapping follows the "normal" behaviour - *technically,* I think it's undefined behaviour to wrap but most implementations simply wrap two positives back to a negative due to the two's complement nature. Be aware then that this is actually non-portable, but what that means in practice is that it will only work on 99.999% of machines out there :-)

But, if you're a stickler for portability, there are better ways to prevent overflow in the first place. I won't go into them here but to say they involve subtracting one of the terms being summed from `MAX_INT` and comparing it to the other term being summed.

Comment: Thanks problem solved. There is problem in generating sieves. The problem is instead of i*i there should be i+i.

Comment: Just on a sidenote, @paxdiablo the input on online judges almost always adhere to the rules and are never wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can get this to give an error is if I enter a value greater than 1000000 or less than 1 to the scanf().

Like this:

```
ubuntu@amrith:/tmp$ ./x
183475666
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@amrith:/tmp$
```

But the reason for that should be obvious. Other than that, this code looks good.

Comment: but the constraint given are 6<n<1000000  .

Comment: All I was saying was that I wasn't able to make it generate a runtime error in any other way. but good that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to find what went wrong!

If the `sizeof(long int)` is `4 bytes` for the OS that you are using, then it makes this problem.
In the code:

```
for(k=i*i;k<N;k+=i)
{
    isprime[k] = 0;
}
```

Here, when you do `k = i*i`, for large values if `i`, the value of `k` goes beyond `4 bytes`and get truncated which may result in negative numbers and so, the condition `k<N` is satisfied but with a negative number :). So you get a segmentation fault there.

It's good that you need only `i+i`, but if you need to increase the limit, take care of this problem.